# HTML <button> form data

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is a coding knowledge question.
I was on the [medium](https://medium.com) platform today and I noticed that they have a blog import section. On inspection I noticed that the field isn't a form rather a div with a `<button>` to submit the value.

It would seem that the value of the div is assigned a data-action attribute.

How does this actually work? Are they using javascript to pull out the data-src?
What is the benefit of this over a normal form field?

Comment: "Are they using javascript to pull out the data-src?" — There isn't any other way to do it.

Comment: "What is the benefit of this over a normal form field?" — It's more complicated and less reliable. Oh, benefits? Can't think of any.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a form dynamically via `javascript`. [AjaxUpload](https://code.google.com/p/ajax-upload/) does that for ya.

Comment: You can, but that doesn't appear to be relevant to the question.